# How to get comments count of each post, in a list of posts that is in a User Dashboard in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Right now in the User Dashboard view (home.blade.php) it wrongly fetches the comments count of the first post by the user.

I would like to display the correct comments count of a post next to the posts' title.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

**View** (home.blade.php)**:**

```
@if(count($posts) > 0)
   <h5>Your Posts ({{ count($posts) }})</h5><hr>
   @foreach($posts as $post)
      <h6><a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}" class="btn btn-link"> {{ $post->title }} </a>             
                                               {{ $comments_count }} comments  </h6><hr>                        
   @endforeach
@endif
```

**Controller:**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id; 
        $user = User::find($user_id); 
     
        $post = Post::with('commentsCount')->first();
        $comments_count = $post->commentsCount->first()->aggregate;
       
        return view('home')->with('posts', $user->posts)
                           ->with('comments_count', $comments_count); 
    }
}
```

**Models** (User, Post, Comment)**:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function posts() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');                            
    }
}


class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
    public $primaryKey = 'id'; 

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 
    }

    public function comments() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment'); 
    }
    
    public function commentsCount() 
    {
        return $this->comments() 
            ->selectRaw('post_id, count(*) as aggregate')
            ->groupBy('post_id');
    }
}


class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comments'; 
    public $primaryKey = 'id'; 

    public function post() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post'); 
    }
}
```

**Migrations** (CreatePostsTable, CreateCommentsTable)**:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->mediumText('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('author');
            $table->integer('post_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->mediumText('comment');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: You code is bit complex, so I added a simple one. Does it work?

Comment: Yes it works but I'm wondering if it's efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **Post** model *`hasMany`* **comments**, so you can able to use [`count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-count) method, like : `$post->comments->count()` :

```
@if(count($posts) > 0)
   <h5>Your Posts ({{ count($posts) }})</h5><hr>
   @foreach($posts as $post)
      <h6><a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}" class="btn btn-link"> {{ $post->title }} </a>             
       {{ $post->comments->count() }} comments  
     </h6>
     <hr>                        
   @endforeach
@endif
```